# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'popincrease'

Tags: python-3.x

```
class city:
     def __init__(self,a,b,c):
         self.name=a
         self.state=b
         self.polpulation=c
     def display(self):
         print("anme of city ",self.name)
     def popincrease(self):
         self.polpulation+=self.polpulation/10

a=city("ddn","utt",10245)
a.display()

new_pop=a.polpulation.popincrease
print(new_pop)
```

error in new_pop. Please help
not able to understad the error..tried typecasting..but it didn't work..

Comment: @Carcigenicate, can you explain further..i am unable to understand :)

Comment: please tell..like what changes should i do ? :)

Comment: tried that...but error coming...."city" object has no attribute 'popincrease'

Comment: It should be `new_pop=a.popincrease()` instead of `new_pop=a.polpulation.popincrease` and you need to return `self.population` from `popincrease` function

Comment: @Chirag , thanks for help...but still getting same error...city object has no attr..........

Comment: @HarshulMalhotra what output is expected? I tested, it's giving me `11269.5`